# Deploying web application to a tomcat server with maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

In **pom.xml** i have this for deploying

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>TomcatLocalServer</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                    <server>TomcatLocalServer</server>
                    <path>/SCPI</path>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
    </build>
```

In **settings.xml** of tomcat server i have this

```
        <server>
            <id>TomcatLocalServer</id>
            <username>andrfas</username>
            <password>1234</password>
        </server>
```

When i'm trying to call maven deploy, i get an error:

```
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/ua/andrfas/SCPI/0.0.1/SCPI-0.0.1.war
184/34421 KB   мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
256/34421 KB   мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
мар 13, 2015 4:04:17 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/ua/andrfas/SCPI/0.0.1/SCPI-0.0.1.pom
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project SCPI: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project SCPI: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:157)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:317)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact ua.andrfas:SCPI:war:0.0.1 from/to TomcatLocalServer (http://localhost:8080/manager): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:662)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:557)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:533)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$PutTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.put(WagonTransporter.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PutTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:204)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:848)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:607)
        ... 43 more
```

The server is running.
I have tried to change tomcat plugin in pom.xml to *tomcat7-maven-plugin*, but i got the same error.
As i understand, it's trying to deploy war file to http://localhost:8080/manager/ua/andrfas/SCPI/0.0.1/SCPI-0.0.1.war. Is this true? If yes, why?
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is a solution for my problem:

Changed the plugin to tomcat7-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatLocalServer</server>
                    <path>/SCPI</path>
                    <username>andrfas</username>
                    <password>1234</password>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Note the url - *http://localhost:8080/manager/text*, not *http://localhost:8080/manager/html*

In tomcat-users.xml added

```
<user username="andrfas" password="1234" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Note the role - manager-script, not the manager-gui.

Finally, running `mvn tomcat7:deploy` according to plugin listed above. Just be careful to run a correct version of plugin.

Comment: You can also use maven cargo plugin to deploy your application . Here is the link : http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/maven-tomcat-deployment-using-cargo